# Firebase Firestore - Async/Await Not Waiting To Get Data Before Moving On?

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I'm new to the "async/await" aspect of JS and I'm trying to learn how it works.

The error I'm getting is Line 10 of the following code. I have created a firestore database and am trying to listen for and get a certain document from the Collection 'rooms'. I am trying to get the data from the doc 'joiner' and use that data to update the innerHTML of other elements.

```
  // References and Variables
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const roomRef = await db.collection('rooms');
  const remoteNameDOM = document.getElementById('remoteName');
  const chatNameDOM = document.getElementById('title');
  let remoteUser;
  // Snapshot Listener
  roomRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(async change => {
      if (roomId != null){
        if (role == "creator"){
          const usersInfo = await roomRef.doc(roomId).collection('userInfo');
          usersInfo.doc('joiner').get().then(async (doc) => {
            remoteUser = await doc.data().joinerName;
            remoteNameDOM.innerHTML = `${remoteUser} (Other)`;
            chatNameDOM.innerHTML = `Chatting with ${remoteUser}`;
          })
        }
      }
    })
  })
})
```

However, I am getting the error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'joinerName' of undefined`

Similarly if I change the lines 10-12 to:

```
remoteUser = await doc.data();
remoteNameDOM.innerHTML = `${remoteUser.joinerName} (Other)`;
chatNameDOM.innerHTML = `Chatting with ${remoteUser.joinerName}`;
```

I get the same error.

My current understanding is that await will wait for the line/function to finish before moving forward, and so remoteUser shouldn't be null before trying to call it. I will mention that sometimes the code works fine, and the DOM elements are updated and there are no console errors.

**My questions:** Am I thinking about async/await calls incorrectly? Is this not how I should be getting documents from Firestore? And most importantly, why does it seem to work only sometimes?

**Edit**: Here are screenshots of the Firestore database as requested by @Dharmaraj. I appreciate the advice.
[image: Rooms Collection to Documents]

[image: userInfo Sub-Collection and Documents within userInfo]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: Hard to say because the code isn't runnable (see [mcve] -- you can mock out the API calls), but it looks like you have a race condition in the loop. Each iteration does not wait for the next and they're all trying to mutate the same DOM nodes, so it's non-deterministic. Even if it was deterministic, it's hard to infer your intent because the last element's calls to `innerHTML` would overwrite all of the previous ones.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Firestore Document as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the use of `async/await` and `then()`, which is not recommended. I propose below a solution based on `Promise.all()` which helps understanding the different arrays that are involved in the code. You can adapt it with `async/await` and a `for-of` loop as @Dharmaraj proposed.

```
roomRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    // snapshot.docChanges() Returns an array of the documents changes since the last snapshot.
    // you may check the type of the change. I guess you maybe don’t want to treat deletions

    const promises = [];
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(docChange => {
        // No need to use a roomId, you get the doc via docChange.doc
        // see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentChange

        if (role == "creator") {  // It is not clear from where you get the value of role...
            const joinerRef = docChange.doc.collection('userInfo').doc('joiner');
            promises.push(joinerRef.get());
        }

    });

    Promise.all(promises)
        .then(docSnapshotArray => {
            // docSnapshotArray is an Array of all the docSnapshots
            // corresponding to all the joiner docs corresponding to all 
            // the rooms that changed when the listener was triggered
            docSnapshotArray.forEach(docSnapshot => {
                remoteUser = docSnapshot.data().joinerName;
                remoteNameDOM.innerHTML = `${remoteUser} (Other)`;
                chatNameDOM.innerHTML = `Chatting with ${remoteUser}`;
            })
        });

});
```

However, what is not clear to me is how you differentiate the different elements of the "first" `snapshot` (i.e. `roomRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {...}))`). If several `rooms` change, the `snapshot.docChanges()` Array will contain several changes and, at the end, you will **overwrite** the `remoteNameDOM` and `chatNameDOM` elements in the last loop.

Or you know upfront that this "first" `snapshot` will ALWAYS contain a single doc (because of the architecture of your app) and then you could simplify the code by just treating the first and unique element as follows:

```
roomRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    const roomDoc = snapshot.docChanges()[0];
    // ...

});
```

Comment: Thanks Renaud! The last part about getting the first snapshot did the trick! Also, you and @ggloren were right that I would be overwriting my elements if there were multiple docs in the snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

There are few mistakes in this:

1. db.collection() does not return a promise and hence await is not necessary there
2. forEach ignores promises so you can't actually use await inside of forEach. for-of is preferred in that case.

Please try the following code:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const roomRef = db.collection('rooms');
const remoteNameDOM = document.getElementById('remoteName');
const chatNameDOM = document.getElementById('title');
let remoteUser;
// Snapshot Listener
roomRef.onSnapshot(async (snapshot) => {
  for (const change of snapshot.docChanges()) {
    if (roomId != null){
      if (role == "creator"){
        const usersInfo = roomRef.doc(roomId).collection('userInfo').doc("joiner");
        usersInfo.doc('joiner').get().then(async (doc) => {
          remoteUser = doc.data().joinerName;
          remoteNameDOM.innerHTML = `${remoteUser} (Other)`;
          chatNameDOM.innerHTML = `Chatting with ${remoteUser}`;
        })
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Dharmaraj! I took your advice and changed the loop from a for-each to a for-of. Unfortunately, the same problem still persists.

Comment: @RichardDao can you add `console.log(snapshot.docChanges())` and share what does it log ?